# How can i interpret "FoxPro" dbf file date time field (eight-byte) in my c++ program?

Tags: date, time, foxpro

I am writing a c++ program to read DBF file of foxpro database .I stumbled upon this date time field of eight bytes.How can i interpret it ? Any help would be highly appreciated ?

Comment: What do you mean under "interpret"? It contains a simple datetime float value.

Comment: @Oleg  "It contains a simple datetime float value".i cant see that i mean what date it is ?

Comment: i want it in human readable form .

Comment: "0E 61 25 00 F8 BF EA 02"  this is the value.it should match to       " 11/21/1994 1:35:39 PM "

Answer (score -2):

The value is a double

The integer part is the day since 1899/12/30

```
internal const double JulianDay_1899_12_30 = 2415019.0;

double d = theValue;
```

in c#

```
return DateTime.FromOADate(d - JulianDay_1899_12_30);
```

see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.fromoadate.aspx

Comment: managed code does give such facility of date manipulation .I found a solution in form of a function written in java . i converted it to c++ and its working fine now .wish unmanaged world had such functionality .